# Getting "Failed decoding transaction data" error for transactions from my custom Safe App

Tags: gnosis-safe

we've added Safe App support to our app at https://www.drips.network/, but not yet requested to list it on the Safe App registry.

Today, one of our users manually added our app to their safe, and reported seeing this strange "Failed decoding transaction data" error on the TX confirmation screen for any transaction the app triggers:

[image]

The "Details" are just "1337". This error doesn't seem to be affecting functionality at all - the transaction can still be triggered, and executes fine. Just wondering what could be causing this error and if there's anything we can do about it from our end.

Comment: You should use customer support for this type of requests

Answer (score 0):

That error is because the gnosis transaction decoder didn't find the corresponding function signature, if you want to see what function is being used in the transaction and what parameters you can use this tool: https://calldata-decoder.apoorv.xyz/, just past the encoded data.